# IPC through writing into files?

Tags: process, operating-system, ipc, shared-memory, data-transfer

I have a question about Inter-process-communication in operating systems.

Can 2 processes communicate with each other by both processes opening the same file (which say was created before both processes, so both processes have the file handler) and then communicating by writing into this file?

If yes, what does this method come under? I have heard that 2 major ways of IPC is by shared-memory and message-passing. Which one of these, this method comes under?
The reason, I am not sure if it comes under shared-memory is that, because this file is not mapped to address space of any of these processes. And, from my understanding, in shared-memory, the shared-memory-region is part of address space of both the processes.

Assume that processes write into the file in some pre-agreed protocol/format so both have no problem in knowing where the other process writes and when etc. This assumption is to merely understand. In real world though, this may be too stringent to hold true etc.

If no, what is wrong with this scenario? Is it that if 2 different processes open the same file, then the changes made by 1st process are not flushed into persistent storage for others to view until the process terminates? or something else?

Any real world example from Windows and Linux should also be useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Using a file is a kind of shared memory. Instead of allocating a common memory buffer in RAM, a common file is used.

To successfully manage the communication some kind of locking mechanism for different ranges in the file is needed. This could either be locking of ranges provided by the file system (available at least on Windows) or global operating system mutexes.

One real-world scenario where disk storage is used for inter-process-communication is the quorom disk used in clusters. It is a common disk resource, accessible over a SAN by all cluster nodes, that stores the cluster's configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The posix system call mmap does mappings of files to virtual memory. If the mapping is shared between two processes, writes to that area in one process will affect other processes. Now coming to you question, yes a process reading from or writing to the underlying file will not always see the same data that the process that has mapped it, since the segment of the file is copied into RAM and periodically flushed to disk. Although I believe you can force synchronization with the msync system call. Do read up on mmap(). It has a host of other memory sharing options.